# Bootstrap4の、指定サイズ「以下」なら表示する方法

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Bootstrap4において、`class="d-none d-md-block"` のような形で、指定サイズ以上であれば表示する、という表現があるかと思います。
これの、指定サイズ「以下」であれば表示する、という方法を探しております。

用途として次のようなことをしております。

```
<p>あいうえお例文 <span class="nobr">あああああああああああああああああああああああ</span> あいうえお例文あいうえお例文あいうえお例文</p>
```

この時、`.nobr` は `*.nobr{white-space:nowrap;}` としており、改行をさせたくない部分に適応しております。
しかし、想定以上に長いものに関しては、スマートフォンの場合横にあふれてしまうため、

```
<p>あいうえお例文
<span class="nobr">ああああああああああああ<br class="d-none d-md-block" />あああああああああああ</span>
あいうえお例文あいうえお例文あいうえお例文</p>
```

のような形で、スマートフォンサイズなら、ここで改行を発生させる、というようにしたいと思っております。
例えば、試していませんがメディアサイズによって異なるよう

```
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    .mb-only{display:none;}
}
@media (max-width: 380px) {
    .mb-only{display:inline;}
}
```

にして、`<br class="d-none d-md-block">`を、`<br class="mb-only" />`のようにすれば出来なくもないかと思うのですが、Bootstrap4に何か書き方があれば、そちらの書き方を使いたいと思っております。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: d-*-none の存在をすっかり忘れてしまっておりました。ご提示いただきましてありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のリファレンスにある通り
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#examples
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

`d-inline`と`d-*-none`を組み合わせればできると思います。
例えばxsのサイズのときだけ表示する場合は

```
.d-inline .d-sm-none
```

smのサイズのときだけ表示する場合は

```
.d-none .d-sm-inline .d-md-none
```